# Nativescript OCR plugin only recognizes the second quadrant of the captured picture in iOS

Tags: ios, nativescript, ocr, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-plugin

First of all, sorry for my English. I'm running my Nativescript Angular App who uses the nativescript OCR 1.0.0 plugin. The recognition works good for Android OS but work partially for iOS. When I run the recognize process I've noticed that only the second quadrant (upper left quadrant) of the picture is recognized. Additionally, the decoding progress goes up 93% or 94%. I have tested in an iPhone 8 and an iPad Air 2 and both have the same behavior.

What can I do in order to use the OCR plugin for iOS and to recognize correctly an image?

Comment: The OCR plugin is not actively maintained, it's recommended to use [Firebase MLKit](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/blob/master/docs/ML_KIT.md), may be you can give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for your advice!